# Multiple 'see more' buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to add multiple 'see more' buttons through out my page. At the moment when when I add a new one only the first button works and it breaks the second. So the first button works fine but when I've tried to copy this thumbnail over and make another one with the same see more details. The second button only changes the first thumbnails 'see more'

```js
function toggle() {
  let Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');

  if (Text.style.display == "none") {
    Text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    Text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.getElementById("moreDetails").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="thumbnail-frame">
  <div id="thumbnail" <div id="details">
    <div id="moreDetails">
      <h3> 001 </h3>
      <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>
      <h4> N00DS </h4>
    </div>
    <button title="Click to Show" type="button" onclick="toggle()">More Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="thumbnail-frame">
  <div id="thumbnail" <div id="details">
    <div id="moreDetails">
      <h3> 002 </h3>
      <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>
      <h4> N00DS </h4>
    </div>
    <button title="Click to Show" type="button" onclick="toggle()">More Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add the button to the HTML and show us how it's not working

Comment: you're probably using the same function `toggle` in other places as well but the ID of the element is hardcoded in function because of it it is not working

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You can't have the same `id` multiple times in an HTML document—it's invalid. Also, you're missing a `>` on two of your opening `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is that you can't have duplicate IDs on a page.  Using classes works ok, or using relative position of your html elements.

```js
function toggle(button){

    // this works because the button is immediately after the "moreDetails" element it pertains to
    let Text = button.previousElementSibling;

    // this would work if you move the button so it is not immediately after moreDetails, but still in the same parent div.
    //let Text = button.parentElement.querySelector(".moreDetails");
    
    if(Text.style.display == "none"){
        Text.style.display= "block";
    }
    else {
        Text.style.display = "none";
    }
}

const moreDetailses = document.querySelectorAll(".moreDetails");
for (let i = 0; i < moreDetailses.length; i++) {
  moreDetailses[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
 <div class="details">

  <div class="moreDetails">

    <h3> 001 </h3>

    <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>

    <h4> N00DS </h4>

  </div>

  <button title="Click to Show"  type="button" onclick="toggle(this)">More Details</button>

</div> 



 <div class="details">

  <div class="moreDetails">

    <h3> 002 </h3>

    <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>

    <h4> N00DS </h4>

  </div>

  <button title="Click to Show"  type="button" onclick="toggle(this)">More Details</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, so classes are for repeating div's on a single page and id's are for single use on one page. For example content div would be an ID, Section for header div and then classes for things within the content to be shown multiple times?

Comment: Correct - if you are making a component that's going to get displayed multiple times on a page, it's better to use classes to "name" the pieces of the component.

Comment: Massive legend <333

Answer (score 0):

An id is only allowed to be used once per page, so that your toggle script will not work as expected when you have multiple elements with the same id.

To make it functional, and keep the required changes to a minimum, you should do the following:

- switch id to class so the HTML is valid
- allow your toggle button to pass along itself, for example `onclick="toggle(this)"`
- move through the dom to get to the element you want to toggle (parentNode, firstChild etc.)

Comment: Hey, so it would have to be moreDetails, moreDetails01, etcetera , if I am doing this 5 + times for multiple see more buttons this seems repetitive, is there a method

Comment: you would use a single function, that moves through the dom - without having to give an id to the target element.
James gave a full code example in his answer.